# Find occurence of string in a text and extract the value

Tags: bash

I need to do the following in bash.

I have,

`env = prod/abcd-ral-5645-test123`
I need to check if the string `ral` exists in `env` and if it exists I need to extract the value `ral-5645` to a different variable.

I have tried to find the occurence of ral as below, but stuck in extracting the text `ral-5645`

```
if [${env} == *"ral"* ];
then
   echo "It's there."
fi
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @j_b  I was ale to find the string occurance. I haven't been able to extract the value i need.

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
grep -o "ral-[0-9]*" env
```

Explanation:

- `[0-9]` means whatever character from 0 to 9 (every possible digit).
- `[0-9]*` means whatever number of digits
- `-o` means "only show the pattern (see `man grep`)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
if [${env} == *"ral"* ];
```

This does not work because the shell does file name globbing, as if you did `ls *ral*`, so you're looking at a list of file names (if anything matches) or the original term `*ral*` if nothing matches.

You can use a regular expression in bash:

```sh
if [[ "$var" =~ .*ral.* ]]
then
    echo "$var matches"
fi
```

To capture, use parens and access the capture via `BASH_REMATCH` where the group count in the regex is the number in the array index.

```sh
if [[ "$var" =~ -(ral.[0-9]+)- ]]
then
    echo "$var matches: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Comment: thank you. This worked. Slight modification to the if statement `if [[ "$var" =~ -(ral-[0-9]+)- ]]`